Как в DBForge вывести только одну строчку
Как в DBForge вывести только одну строчку. Ни TOP 1, ни LIMIT 1 не работает
СУБД Oracle

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

dbforge это инструмент. Какая СУБД у вас?

microsoft sql server
Оператор SELECT, если что

top 1 должен работать. select top 1 * from table

Прошу прощения, у меня Oracle

Что бы вывести 1 или несколько первых строк запроса в Oracle, надо задать ограничение в where
Первая строка
select * from my_table where rownum = 1

Первые 10 строк
select * from my_table where rownum > 11

Надо так же учитывать, что это ограничение работает наравне с остальными условиями where и до сортировки
Если надо выбрать какие то значения из БД по фильтру и потом взять первую строку, то надо использовать вложенный запрос
select * from (
    select * from my_table 
    where field1 = 2 and field2 = 3
    order by field3 DESC
)
where rownum = 1

Так же можно обойтись без вложенных запросов при сортировке, используя FETCH FIRST
select * from my_table
where field1 = 2 and field2 = 3
order by field3 ASC 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY

